# Partitioning processing of each chunk in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch framework. I am seeking for a solution for below requirement.

Let say there are 5000 records in data base table.I want 5 chunks to be created(That is each chunk is processing 1000 records) & processing of each chunk should be partitioned (1000 records by 5 partitions where each partition process 200 records).

This is different from partitioning config as below.

```
        <batch:step id="partitionRBMRead" next="job1.flow1">                
            <batch:partition partitioner="rbmPartitioner" step="readDataFromRBM">       
                <batch:handler grid-size="50" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>   
            </batch:partition>              
        </batch:step>                   

        <batch:flow parent="generateCsvFlow" id="job1.flow1" />
    </batch:job>
```

Because according to this configuration it creates partitions first & processes them in parallel. But what I want is executing 5 chunks (of size 1000) sequentially & processing each chunk with 5 parallel threads.

Chunk 1 (Record 1 to 1000) => partition 1 (Record 1 to 200)|| partition 2 (Record 201 to 400) || partition 3 (Record 401 to 600) || partition 4 (Record 601 to 800) || partition 5 (Record 801 to 1000)

Chunk 2 (Record 1001 to 2000) => partition 1 (Record 1001 to 1200)|| partition 2 (Record 1201 to 1400) || partition 3 (Record 1401 to 1600) || partition 4 (Record 1601 to 1800) || partition 5 (Record 1801 to 2000)

Can any one please help me out of it? Thanks.

Comment: first thought: FirstPartitionStep (break the 5000 apart, gridsize=1=sequential)
wraps anotherPartitionStep (break the 1000 apart, gridsize=5=parallel), really just a quick thought